# Call Python from .NET

Tags: c#, python, .net, python.net

I have some code written in Python which can not be transferred to a .NET language. I need to call one of these functions from my .NET WinForms application.

Now, I do it by starting the Python script as a separate process and pass parameters to it as command line arguments. It works, but I don't really like this solution. I'd like to improve it to a better one.

Is there any better way to call a function of a `.py` script from a .NET application? What is the best way to do it?

Note: **IronPython is NOT an option** for this Python script

Comment: "don't really like this solution"  Why not?  It works.  It's simple and reliable.  What's wrong with it?

Comment: @S.Lott: It's not quite "enterprisy" enough.

Comment: Thx for your comment. Starting a process only for calling a function is not the best thing Also when pc is heavily used, starting a new process can take a while (This script is used heavily - 3-5 times a minute whan my app is running and important to be very fast). Installing my app is heavier: python is required on target machines beside .net, installing it not trivial for a regular user. So, for me it is not simple and not a good one.

Comment: @Tom: Why aren't you using Pipes to pass data into a Python process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It works, but I don't really like this solution, I'd like to improve it to a better one.

No, AFAIK there isn't a better solution, especially if IronPython is a no-no for you. So you could still keep this as a temporary workaround while waiting for the script to be migrated to .NET or until you find that someone already wrote a library on .NET that provides you with similar functionality.

Comment: Sad news. Thx for all answers from everybody, but as I see there is no effecient, widely used way to do it.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov, I recommend looking at Python.NET (Python for .NET) and maybe you can re-consider your answer.

Answer (score 10):

This might be a lot more work than launching the Python process, but here's an alternate solution.

You can [embed Python](http://docs.python.org/extending/embedding.html) into another program.  The API is for C and Interop from .NET will probably be a major pain.  If you're into a bit of a safer way to handle the native Python API, you can look into [`Boost.Python`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/python/doc/), which, among its less advertised features, has [support for embedding](http://wiki.python.org/moin/boost.python/EmbeddingPython).

With these tools, you can write a C++ managed DLL that uses `Boost.Python` to load the Python interpreter and execute any Python script.  Thus, you can execute any Python code *directly* in the hosting process, eliminating the use of an external process and any form of IPC.

**Edit**: AFAIK, all you have to add to your installation procedure is the deployment of the Python DLL and `Boost.Python` DLL.

Answer (score 5):

Besides the COM option, you could make your Python script instantiate a xmlrpc server - 
it is quite transparent and you never have to deal with "xml" on your own code.

Then, on .net side, you simply connect to your python app via xmlrpc - if there is no suitable way to do that in C#, just write a client function in IronPython.

The SimpleXMLRPCServer example on Python documentation is enough for that:

http://docs.python.org/library/simplexmlrpcserver.html

Answer (score 5):

I think you need to re-evaluate Carlos' answer.
See the section Implementing COM Objects with Python in Mark Hammond's book Python Programming on Win32.

You should be able to create a COM object, then have .Net interact with it.

From the book the following will create a COM server with a single method.

```
# SimpleCOMServer.py - A sample COM server - almost as small as they come!
# 
# We expose a single method in a Python COM object.
class PythonUtilities:
    _public_methods_ = [ 'SplitString' ]
    _reg_progid_ = "PythonDemos.Utilities"
    # NEVER copy the following ID 
    # Use "print pythoncom.CreateGuid()" to make a new one.
    _reg_clsid_ = "{41E24E95-D45A-11D2-852C-204C4F4F5020}"

    def SplitString(self, val, item=None):
        import string
        if item != None: item = str(item)
        return string.split(str(val), item)

# Add code so that when this script is run by
# Python.exe, it self-registers.
if __name__=='__main__':
    print "Registering COM server..."
    import win32com.server.register
    win32com.server.register.UseCommandLine(PythonUtilities)
```

The book goes on to say ".. you can do this by executing the code as a normal Python script. The easiest way to do this is to open the source file in PythonWin and use the Run command from the File menu. "

I think you need the ActivePython distribution from Activestate to do it.

See this question [Consuming Python COM Server from .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1054849/consuming-python-com-server-from-net)

Answer (score 3):

Create a COM .dll from a .py script and use Interop in your .NET code.
Have a look here: http://docs.python.org/faq/windows.html

Comment: At first I thought you meant that the Python interpreter is available as a COM object, but the page you linked to says nothing about COM. So it sounds like your answer is actually about *writing your own* COM object, and rolling all the associated infrastructure.

Answer (score 3):

[PythonNet](https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet) should help with this one. It enables you to call python code from C#.

A cleaner way is to expose the python script via a [Flask REST API](http://flask.pocoo.org/) and consume that from your .NET Application. Don't forget to put [proper authentication](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-OpenID/) in place.