# Call python script from .Net Core using pythonnet

Tags: c#, python, .net, .net-core, python.net

I'm trying to get pythonnet to work in my .Net Core app running on Linux.

I've made a reference to **Python.Runtime.dll** (which I got from [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/pythonnet/2.3.0-py27-dotnet)) in my .Net Core project.

My code is:

```
using System;
using Python.Runtime;
namespace pythonnet_w
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Start");
            using (**Py.GIL()**) {
            //     blabla
            }
            Console.WriteLine("End");
        }
    }
}
```

I get this runtime error:

```
 Unhandled Exception: System.MissingMethodException: Method not found:     'System.Reflection.Emit.AssemblyBuilder      
 System.AppDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(System.Reflection.AssemblyName, System.Reflection.Emit.AssemblyBuilderAccess)'.
    at Python.Runtime.CodeGenerator..ctor()
    at Python.Runtime.DelegateManager..ctor()
    at Python.Runtime.PythonEngine.Initialize(IEnumerable`1 args, Boolean setSysArgv)
    at Python.Runtime.PythonEngine.Initialize(Boolean setSysArgv)
    at Python.Runtime.PythonEngine.Initialize()
    at Python.Runtime.Py.GIL()
    at pythonnet_w.Program.Main(String[] args) in D:\Development\~.Net libraries (3.part)\phytonnet\.Net Core test (phytonnet)\c#\pythonnet_test\Program.cs:line 10
 /usr/sbin/pythonnet_w: line 5: 19487 Aborted                 dotnet "/usr/share/pythonnet_wit/pythonnet_w.dll"
```

Tried to find a solution in these threads but without any luck:

[How do I run a py file in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53594509/how-do-i-run-a-py-file-in-c)

[Call Python from .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6624503/call-python-from-net)

**UPDATE:**

I tried to open \pythonnet-master\src\runtime**Python.Runtime.csproj** in Visual Studio to see if I can compile it to .Net or .Core, but I can only compile to .Net framework.
I found this article "[How to port from .net framework to .net standard](https://codehollow.com/2017/05/port-net-framework-net-standard/)"
Is that what I have to do?

Comment: .NET Core support is in master branch

Comment: I'm not sure what that mean, in term of how I get this "master branch" to a library I can actually use in my .Net project? Do I have to compile it myself and enable Core support somehow?

Comment: yes, read here: https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet/issues/96

Comment: installation wiki: https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet/wiki/Installation

Comment: Please see my UPDATE....it this my only option?
If other already did this I would love to have a copy of the project or the .dll

Comment: see my response: https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet/issues/96#issuecomment-445359059

Comment: I give up. After several attempts to compile the master code I never succeeded in making a working .NET Standard library that I can use in Linux :-(

Comment: Can you summarize the unresolved issues?

Comment: I have the exact same exception with the master branch (v2.4). I'm targetting .Net Core 2.1 on Windows 10 machine.

Answer (score 6):

I finally had success by using a self-compiled Python.Runtime.dll as of version 2.4.0. There are two options to create a working DLL:

- Remove the other target framework `net461` from the respective project file (leaving only `netstandard2.0`).
- Run `dotnet build` using the appropriate options

For option 2, the following **works**(in Windows, Mac and Linux):

1. Clone the pythonnet repo (https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet)
2. In the pythonnet folder, `cd src\runtime`
3. Run `dotnet build -c ReleaseWinPY3 -f netstandard2.0 Python.Runtime.15.csproj` in Windows(in Mac/Linux, replace `ReleaseWinPY3` with `ReleaseMonoPY3` because the former use `python37` and the later use `python3.7`)
4. Set `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` in Mac or `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` in linux(Windows skip):

```
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib
```

5. Use the built DLL `bin\netstandard2.0\Python.Runtime.dll` as DLL reference in your Visual Studio .NET Core project (mine targets `netcoreapp2.2`, `netcoreapp3.1` is also tested ok), e.g. in conjunction with the following code,

```cs
using System;
using Python.Runtime;

namespace Python_CSharp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (Py.GIL())
            {
                dynamic os = Py.Import("os");
                dynamic dir = os.listdir();
                Console.WriteLine(dir);

                foreach (var d in dir)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(d);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I had to use the configuration 'ReleaseMonoPY3' instead of 'ReleaseWinPY3' to get it to work, otherwise it tried to load python37 and kernel32 instead of libpython3.7m.so. Ubuntu16 + dotnet core

Comment: You, sir, deserve a cookie!

Comment: I tried this, but I get the error: "An unhandled exception of type 'System.DllNotFoundException' occurred in Python.Runtime.dll: 'Unable to load shared library 'python38' or one of its dependencies. In order to help diagnose loading problems, consider setting the DYLD_PRINT_LIBRARIES environment variable: dlopen(libpython38, 1): image not found'"

I've installed python 3.8.1 via pyenv (and homebrew) but I'm using the pyenv version by default by setting my path to that install... am I missing something here (On macos)... Is there a way I can hard code/copy a python library for this to use?

Comment: I had success when I put python.exe and DLLs into the same directory as the runtime DLL. Did not test with other paths, as I do not have a system-wide installation of Python.

Answer (score 1):

You can host the IronPython interpreter right in your .NET application. For example, using NuGet, you can download the right package and then embed the script execution (actually the IronPython engine) right into your application.

Ref: 
https://medium.com/better-programming/running-python-script-from-c-and-working-with-the-results-843e68d230e5

Comment: I started her(with ironpython) but found it is only compatible with python 2.xx. is this right? Seems to be an accepted fact in all my searches.

Comment: I have tried using IronPython. It has worked great for alot of functions. But I ran into issues (native exceptions) when calling functions from the pyserial library. I have since moved to pythonnet with no issue. Just a bit more complicated to get started with. Check the wiki's if you try it.