# Portable Python com server using pywin32

Tags: python, vb.net, vba, winapi, pywin32

Is it possible to run comserver without requiring elevation.

For example I am able to run code from Python.TestServer (below) but it requires elevation.

Python.TestServer code is at: [Consuming Python COM Server from .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1054849/consuming-python-com-server-from-net)

Is it possible to run com server which doesn't require elevation so that I can run com object without having Administrative password.

for example

```
import pythoncom
from win32com.server import localserver

class demoObj(object):
    _reg_clsctx_ = pythoncom.CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER
    _reg_clsid_ = "{FA501660-8BB0-42F6-842B-A757FA3098DC}"
    _reg_desc_ = "Demo COM server"
    _reg_progid_ = "Python.Demo"
    _public_methods_ = ['hello']

def hello(self, who):
    return "Hellow " + who

localserver.serve('B83DD222-7750-413D-A9AD-01B37021B24B')
```

I have tried above code but it says `pywintypes.com_error: (-2147221005, 'Invalid class string', None, None)`

how to make the valid class string for local server?

Example vba :

```
Sub demodemo()
    Set obj = CreateObject("Python.Demo")
    Debug.Print obj.Hello("World")
End Sub
```

Comment: The Com server will be consumed by VBA. What is your problem with vba?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what are you trying to do?  I know that in vba there are other alternatives to link excel and python

Comment: have you tried xlwings?

Comment: Sorry for late reply as I was on vacation! I want to use python for Microsoft Word and not excel. I tried `import xlwings as xw; xw.serve()` but I don't know how to use that from vba (word).

Comment: I have several other potential consumers of Python code, so COM is the best choice at least for me.  I don't want to shell out, rather use variant arguments and results and not files.  xlwings and pyxll and fiends won't do, not necessarily xl.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's possible to register and use a class without privileges. The class has to be registered in the current user instead of all users.
The option is not provided, so you'll have to register it yourself by writing the keys in `HKCU\SOFTWARE\Classes`.

Here's a working example:

```
import os, sys, win32api, win32con, win32com.server.register

class HelloWorld(object):
  _reg_progid_ = "Python.TestServer"
  _reg_clsid_ = "{7CC9F362-486D-11D1-BB48-0000E838A65F}"
  _reg_desc_ = "Python Test COM Server"
  _public_methods_ = ['Hello']

  def Hello(self):
    return "Hello!"



def RegisterClass(cls):
  file = os.path.abspath(sys.modules[cls.__module__].__file__)
  folder = os.path.dirname(file)
  module = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(file))[0]
  python = win32com.server.register._find_localserver_exe(1)
  python = win32api.GetShortPathName(python)
  server = win32com.server.register._find_localserver_module()
  command = '%s "%s" %s' % (python, server, cls._reg_clsid_)
  typename = module + "." + cls.__name__

  def write(path, value):
    win32api.RegSetValue(win32con.HKEY_CURRENT_USER, path, win32con.REG_SZ, value)

  write("SOFTWARE\\Classes\\" + cls._reg_progid_ + '\\CLSID', cls._reg_clsid_)
  write("SOFTWARE\\Classes\\AppID\\" + cls._reg_clsid_, cls._reg_progid_)
  write("SOFTWARE\\Classes\\CLSID\\" + cls._reg_clsid_, cls._reg_desc_)
  write("SOFTWARE\\Classes\\CLSID\\" + cls._reg_clsid_ + '\\LocalServer32', command)
  write("SOFTWARE\\Classes\\CLSID\\" + cls._reg_clsid_ + '\\ProgID', cls._reg_progid_)
  write("SOFTWARE\\Classes\\CLSID\\" + cls._reg_clsid_ + '\\PythonCOMPath', folder)
  write("SOFTWARE\\Classes\\CLSID\\" + cls._reg_clsid_ + '\\PythonCOM', typename)
  write("SOFTWARE\\Classes\\CLSID\\" + cls._reg_clsid_ + '\\Debugging', "0")

  print("Registered %s" % cls.__name__)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  RegisterClass(HelloWorld)
```

Comment: Seems like working. Sorry For Being Late To Reply. I Was On Vacation